# How to wait for a callback passed to Flask-SocketIO's emit()?

Tags: flask, callback, socket.io, blocking, flask-socketio

Is there a way in `Flask-SocketIO` to have a *blocking/synchronous* `emit('event', callback)` function that **waits for the callback passed to it before returning**?

**Or** -- is there a way to ***directly*** invoke the callback in an `@socketio.on('event')` handler instead of the plain `return` from that handler?

---

## This is my situation specifically:

```
+-----------------+                            +----------------------+                         +----------------------+
|     Browser     |  emit('serverGiveData',    |        Flask         |  emit('workerGiveData', |       Worker         |
|  (webapp, JS)   |       browser_callback)    |      web server      |       server_callback)  |   (Python program)   |
|                 | +------------------------> |                      | +-------------------->  |                      |
|                 |                            |                      |                         |                      |
| socket.io 1.7.3 |            data            | Flask-SocketIO 2.8.2 |          data           |socketiIO-client 0.7.2|
|                 | <------------------------+ |                      | <--------------------+  |                      |
|                 |                            |                      |                         |                      |
+-----------------+                            +----------------------+                         +----------------------+
```

So the **Browser** wants **data** from the **Worker** and the **Flask web server** is just a proxy in between.

I would like the `browser_callback()` to be invoked after the **Server** receives the **data** from the **Worker**.
(I.e. I would like to call the `browser_callback()` from the `server_callback()`).

***However***, I cannot invoke the `browser_callback()` from `server_callback()` manually in Flask-SocketIO -- it is "automatically" invoked when I return from `'serverGiveData'` handler function on the **Server**. That is why I would like to have a *blocking/synchronous* `emit('workerGiveData')` so that the handler on the **Server** doesn't return before the **Worker** delivers the data.

---

## Here's the code

#### Browser

```js
socketio.emit('serverGiveData', args, function (data) {
    console.log('Received data');
});
```

#### Server

```py
@socketio.on('serverGiveData')
def handler(msg):
    socketio.emit('workerGiveData', msg, callback=server_callback)
    return  # When server_callback() gets called back

def server_callback(data):
    print('Received data from Worker')
    # Here I want to invoke client_callback(), i.e.
    # I don't want handler() to return before this server_callback() is invoked
```

#### Worker

```py
def handler(args, callback);
    callback(data)

socketIO.on('workerGiveData', handler)
```

---

(I am aware I could `emit('heyBrowserHeresData')` from the `server_callback()` when the Worker delivers the data and listen on that event in the browser with `browser_callback()` code as the handler.
I would like to avoid that jumble.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Socket.IO protocol is event-based, not request/response based. I recommend that you don't use the callbacks, those are for quick acknowledgement that an event was received, not to provide results after some work was done.

Try this instead to use a new event to replace your callback:

```
+-----------------+                            +----------------------+                         +----------------------+
|     Browser     |  emit('serverGiveData’)    |        Flask         |  emit('workerGiveData', |       Worker         |
|  (webapp, JS)   |                            |      web server      |       server_callback)  |   (Python program)   |
|                 | +------------------------> |                      | +-------------------->  |                      |
|                 |                            |                      |                         |                      |
| socket.io 1.7.3 |  emit(‘dataForBrowser’)    | Flask-SocketIO 2.8.2 |          data           |socketiIO-client 0.7.2|
|                 | <------------------------+ |                      | <--------------------+  |                      |
|                 |                            |                      |                         |                      |
+-----------------+                            +----------------------+                         +----------------------+
```

You can leave the second callback on the server-side if that works well for you, or less you can also replace it with an event.